# Images not being loaded through img tag in html

Tags: angular

I have a project and I'm trying to add an image to a component through img tag in html file, that is located in **angularNode7Teste/thumbsup-jpg** (the app root folder). The component files are located in **angularNode7Teste/src/app** folder.

Here is the code from my app.component.html:

```
<h1>
 {{title}}
</h1>

<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Send" >
<img src="../../thumbs-up.jpg"/>
<div class="image"></div>
```

This is the app.component.css file:

```
div.image {
    content: url(../../thumbs-up.jpg);
}
```

The image in `<img src="../../thumbs-up.jpg"/>` doesn't renderize, but the div tag `<div class="image"></div>` is renderizing normally.

The image is the same in both tags, I'm referencing the same image to see if it works but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular `index.html` contains the `<base href="/">` element which sets the base path for your URLs. So you will need to check this element `href` attribute value. Angular uses this element for routing purposes.

**Regarding `<img>`:** If `src` URL is relative then will be relative in respect to the `href` value of `<base>` element.

**Regarding CSS `url()`:** URL will be relative to the CSS file.

**Example:**

Having an image located in Angular CLI project at `src/assets/img/mypic.jpg`.

Then this will work `<img src="assets/img/mypic.jpg" />`.

For the CSS file located at `src/app/app.component.css` the following will be valid:

```
.pic {
  background-image: url('../assets/img/mypic.jpg');
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
}
```

Comment: You can only place your images inside assets folder? I've tried to move the image inside the assets folder and reference it in the app.component.html file and it worked, but if the image is not in that folder, it doesn't renderize.

Comment: @William yes, all the assets need to be in that folder. In fact this is configurable from `.angular-cli.json`, check `assets` property. Config schema is available [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli). In the end the app will be built, thus using webpack to bundle css and js and have the assets placed separately. When going to production you will do `ng build --prod` and the `dist` folder will contain your build that can be placed on a server. You can check the contents of that folder to see if is looking good for you.